# How to avoid if statements which returns value based on the input in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have input as roleID (of Long data type), so I can not use switch case,
I am using if else statements right now.
I have search for the solution but have not came across with the perfect one.

```
RoleEnum fetchProcessForRole(roleID) {
    if (RoleEnum.USER.equals(roleID) {
        return RoleEnum.USER_VALIDATION; // this is of int type
    } else if (RoleEnum.ADMIN.equals(roleID) {
        return RoleEnum.ADMIN_VALIDATION;
    } else if (RoleEnum.MGR.equals(roleID) {
        return RoleEnum.MGR_VALIDATION;
    }
}

RoleEnum {
    USER(1,"USER","userrpt"),
    ADMIN(2,"ADMIN","adminrpt"),
    MGR(3,"MGR","mgrrpt"),
    USER_VALIDATION(4,"USER_VALIDATION","userrpt"),
    ADMIN_VALIDATION(5,"ADMIN_VALIDATION","adminrpt"),
    MGR_VALIDATION(6,"MGR_VALIDATION","mgrrpt");
    // it have int id, String name and its getters
}
```

I want to know if there is any other way to achieve same thing, as the input is Long, I do not want to use switch as it will require lot of conversions.

Comment: Just use switch. It's still available in Java 8. You can also make a set of the enum constants you want (In Java 9, you can use `Set.of()`), and then use `set.contains`

Comment: Looks that two enums should be used here, one Role and one RoleValidation (or RoleProcess according to your method's name). This would allow RoleValidation values to initialise themselves with a Role value directly, meaning no more `if`, simply something like `roleID.getRoleValidation()`.

Comment: @user I am getting input in Long type, can not use switch, even if I try to convert it o long, it will need to convert at every case as well, And after doing all this may be code will not get approved. ;(

Comment: @sp00m good suggestion but this is how it is in existing code and not allowed to touch existing structure.

Comment: @Kamini by the way, you don't need to store the name of the enum values - I'm pretty sure `USER.name()` is adequate

Comment: Why you are using `USER` and `USER_VALIDATION` both  just for checking ?

Comment: @Eklavya it has to go into database for further process. inside procedure it will get call. Its just example I can not disclose the real code here.

Comment: _USER_ and  _USER_VALIDATION_ have same id?

Comment: @HadiJ No, sorry I will update in the question. thanks for noticing

Comment: Why did you tag `java-stream`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get enum using `roleId`

```
RoleEnum role =
        EnumSet.allOf(RoleEnum.class).stream().filter(r -> r.getId() == roleId).findFirst().orElseThrow();
```

Then use switch-case to get result no conversion needed.

```
RoleEnum result;
switch (role) {
  case USER :
    result = RoleEnum.USER_VALIDATION;
    break;
  case ADMIN :
    result = RoleEnum.ADMIN_VALIDATION;
    break;
  case MGR :
    result = RoleEnum.MGR_VALIDATION;
    break;
  default:
    result = null;
 }
```

Comment: `findFirst().orElseThrow` goes better for enum values, since they are mostly exhaustive.

Comment: @Eklavya its giving compilation error "An enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of eumeration constant"

Comment: @Kamini I used your given data it's working check here https://onlinegdb.com/B1eAxGZ3U

Comment: @Kamini May be you use like `case RoleEnum.USER` which is wrong use like this `case USER`

Comment: @Eklavya yes tried with this one and its working , thanks. I have also find out way with stream api.. Please look answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a static class that stores enum constants on the map. because the third argument for pair of enum constants is the same(`USER` & `USER_VALIDATION` and ...) you can init the map base on this param. so the map will initial `map<String, RoleEnum>` which the key is third param and value is enum constant. 
consider this fact that I supposed `USER_VALIDATION` comes after `USER` and for others too. after finding the `roleEnum` based on id then you can get pair of it from the map based on `roleEnum`'s third param.

```
enum RoleEnum {
  USER(1, "USER", "userrpt"),
  ADMIN(2, "ADMIN", "adminrpt"),
  MGR(3, "MGR", "mgrrpt"),
  USER_VALIDATION(4, "USER_VALIDATION", "userrpt"),
  ADMIN_VALIDATION(5, "ADMIN_VALIDATION", "adminrpt"),
  MGR_VALIDATION(6, "MGR_VALIDATION", "mgrrpt");

  static class Holder {
     private static HashMap<String, RoleEnum> map = new HashMap<>();

     public HashMap<String, RoleEnum> getMap() {
        return map;
     }
  }

  private long id;
  private String name;
  private String des;

  RoleEnum(long id, String name, String des) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.des = des;
    Holder.map.put(this.getDes(), this);
  }

  public static Map<String, RoleEnum> getMap() {
    return Holder.map;
  }

 public static RoleEnum findById(Long id) {
     RoleEnum roleEnum = EnumSet.allOf(RoleEnum.class)
            .stream().filter(role -> role.getId() == id)
            .findFirst().orElse(null);
     return getMap().get(roleEnum.getDes());
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to return  RoleEnum of  different id  depend on the input

Comment: I don't get the part of creating a `Holder` map with `des` as keys not even grouping by it and then looking up the map based on a `findFirst` for `id` used in filter among values!

Comment: @Naman, As you see third param for pair of (USER, USER_VALIDATION & ADMIN,ADMIN_VALIDATION ) are same. so i decided  work based on this param. the map that is declared in the Holder class will initial by third param as a key and enum constant as value. since there duplicate keys map will fill by _*_VALIDATION_ as values. the id that OP wants to find the enum constant is for (USER,ADMIN,MGR) so in the _findById_ method first find the enum constant by id and then find the pair of found constant in the map by third param.

Comment: Since you are accessing the `Holder.map` right in the constructor of `RoleEnum`, there is no point in creating the nested class `Holder`; you can place the `map` variable right in the `RoleEnum` class. Further, you can map from the id to the end result in the first place, then, `findById()` only needs a map lookup. Well, for id values in the range 1…3, you don’t even need a map, an array would do as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not allowed to touch `RoleEnum`, and you have tests to prove the order of enums never changes, and another set of tests to prove the id's are in increasing order from 1, then you could possibly do such an abomination:

```
RoleEnum fetchProcessForRole(long roleID) {
    RoleEnum[] values = RoleEnum.values();
    if (roleID < 1 || roleID > values.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Role id not found");
    }
    return values[(int) roleID - 1];
}
```

But you really should just store it all in an id:enum map.

Answer (score 0):

So couple things to note. What does the equals method for enum look like if you have overridden it. Is it a simple check to see if the roleId is equal to the enums id:

```
public boolean equals(long roleId) {
   return (int) roleId == id
}
```

But I think the best way to approach this is to use a Map:

```
HashMap<int, RoleEnum> validation = new HashMap<int, RoleEnum>();

RoleEnum fetchProcessForRole(long roleId){
   return validation.get((int) roleId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the `RoleEnum` is under your control or not.

But I don't understand what is represents

1. User's role
2. Validation required for a user's role
3. Both

I think it represents option 3, perhaps required in your use case. But it has more than one reason to change. Please consider segregating them.

If you do so, your function changes to accept a `RoleEnum` and return a `RoleValidationEnum`.

You can use a `switch` to decide which `RoleEnum` returns which `RoleValidationEnum`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got below solution on this.

```
RoleEnum fetchProcessForRole(Long roleID) {

String name= RoleEnum.values()[int(long)roleID].getName().toUpperCase();
return EnumSet.allOf(RoleEnum.class).stream()
            .filter(role -> role.getName().startsWith(name+"_"))
            .findFirst()
            .get();

}
```